# GWT - view and presenter for each tabs

Tags: java, gwt

I hava a view and presenter for single page with TabPanel like this:

```
<g:TabPanel ui:field="tabPanel" addStyleNames="{style.versionTabs}">
    <g:Tab text="1">
        <g:FlowPanel>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:Tab>
    <g:Tab text="2">
        <g:FlowPanel>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:Tab>
    <g:Tab text="2">
        <g:FlowPanel>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:Tab>
</g:TabPanel>
```

For each tab I want to create new Presenter and View to separete code between tabs.

```
@UiHandler("tabPanel")
    void onTabSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
        if (event.getSelectedItem() == ONE) {
            presenter.showOne();
        }
        if (event.getSelectedItem() == TWO) {
            presenter.showTwo();
        }
        if (event.getSelectedItem() == THREE) {
            presenter.showThree();
        }
    }
```

Then I have simple view and presenter (i have three presenters and views)

```
public class OneView extends Composite implements IOneView {

    @UiTemplate("OneView.ui.xml")
    interface OneViewUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, OneView> {
    }

    private static OneViewUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(OneViewUiBinder.class);

    @UiField
    Button startButton;

    public oneView() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        return this;
    }
}


<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" 
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        Hallo,
        <g:Button ui:field="startButton" text="exemplary text" />
    </g:HTMLPanel>
```

And presenter

```
public class OnePresenter implements IOnePresenter {

    private IOneView view;
    private final Messages translation;

    public OnePresenter(ClientFactoryImpl factory, Messages messages) {
        this.view = factory.getOneView();
        this.translation = messages;
    }


    @Override
    public void go(HasWidgets container) {
        container.clear();
        container.add(view.asWidget());
    }
    @Override
    public void init() {    
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I create new presenter after user click in tab in main presenter i don't see button

What I doing wrong?

Comment: this is probably typo, but you have mismatch between class name and constructor name in `OneView` class, the other thing is, you are calling methods in your presenter, `showOne`,`showTwo`,`showThree`, in your class presenter you have mothod `go(hasWidget container)`  but you didn't provide any code how one method invoke another, because your problem might be there

Comment: Which code need I to provide?

Comment: it will be good if you provide sources which showing how from this call `presenter.showOne();` you get to place where you adding your view to panel